# Are string constants overrated?

Tags: string, constants

It's easy to lose track of odd numbers like `0`, `1`, or `5`.  I used to be very strict about this when I wrote low-level C code. As I work more with all the string literals involved with XML and SQL, I find myself often breaking the rule of embedding constants in code, at least when it comes to string literals.  (I'm still good about numeric constants.)

Strings aren't the same as numbers.  It feels tedious and a little silly to create a compile-time constant that has the same name as its value (E.g. `const string NameField = "Name";`), and although the repetition of the same string literal in many locations seems risky, there's little chance of a typo thanks to copying and pasting, and when I refactor I'm usually doing a global search that involves changing more than just the name of the thing, like how it's treated functionally in relation to the things around it.

So, let's say you don't have a good XML serializer (or aren't in the mood to set one up).  Which of these would you personally use (if you weren't trying to bow to peer pressure in some code review):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...other code...

    XmlNode node = ...;

    Console.WriteLine(node["Name"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node["Color"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node["Taste"].InnerText);

    // ...other code...
}
```

or:

```
class Fruit
{
    private readonly XmlNode xml_node;

    public Fruit(XmlNode xml_node)
    {
        this.xml_node = xml_node;
    }

    public string Name
    { get { return xml_node["Name"].InnerText; } }

    public string Color
    { get { return xml_node["Color"].InnerText; } }

    public string Taste
    { get { return xml_node["Taste"].InnerText; } }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...other code...

    XmlNode node = ...;
    Fruit fruit_node = new Fruit(node);

    Console.WriteLine(fruit_node.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(fruit_node.Color);
    Console.WriteLine(fruit_node.Taste);

    // ...other code...
}
```

Comment: 0 is not an odd number, it's even :-)

Answer (score 11):

A defined constant is easier to refactor.  If "Name" ends up being used three times and you change it to "FullName", changing the constant is one change instead of three.

Comment: The OP's point is that a global search-and-replace (in an IDE or a text editor) will catch all three in one operation.

Comment: @Eddie, it will also catch every other use of "Name"

const string XmlNodeName = "Name";
const string AddressName = "Name";
const string XmlFruitName = "Name";

What if you hardcoded "Name" everywhere and only the XmlNodeName changed?

Comment: Yeah global search and replace is even more dangerous than using hardcoded strings. Even more so when they're being used to replace hardcoded strings.

Comment: @Dour High Arch:  Yes, I agree with you.  I was just pointing out the OP's context of the question.

Answer (score 5):

For something like that it depends on how often the constant is used. If it's just in one place as per your example, then hard-coding is fine. If it's used in many different places, definitely use a constant. One typo could lead to hours of debugging if you're not careful, because your compiler isn't going to notice that you typed "Tsate" instead of "Taste", while it WILL notice that you typed fruit_node.Tsate instead of fruit_node.Taste.

Edit:
I see now that you mentioned copying and pasting, but if you're doing that you may also be losing the time you save by not creating a constant in the first place. With intellisense and auto-completion, you could have the constant out there in a few keystrokes, instead of going through the trouble of copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably guessed. The answer is: it depends on the context.

It depends on what the example code is part of. If it's just part of a small throw away system then hard coding the constants may be acceptable.

If it's part of a large, complex system and the constants will be used in mulitple files, I'd be more drawn to the second option.

Answer (score 0):

As in many matters of programming, this is a matter of taste. The "laws" of proper programming were created from experience -- many people have been burned by global variables causing namespace or clarity problems, so Global Variables Are Evil. Many have used magic numbers, only to later discover that the number was wrong or needed changing. Text search is ill-suited to changing these values, so Constants In Code Are Evil.

But both are permitted, because sometimes they *aren't* evil. You need to make the decision yourself -- which leads to clearer code? Which is going to be better for maintainers? Does the reasoning behind the original rule apply to my situation? If I had to read or maintain this code later, how would I rather that it were written?

There is no absolute law of good coding style, because no two programmers' minds works exactly alike. The rule is to write the clearest, cleanest code that you can.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd load the fruit from the XML file in advance - something like:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public Fruit(string name, Color color, string taste)
    {
        this.Name = name;  this.Color = color; this.Taste = taste;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Color Color { get; private set; }
    public string Taste { get; private set; }
}

// ... In your data access handling class...
    public static FruitFromXml(XmlNode node) 
    { 
            // create fruit from xml node with validation here 
    }
}
```

That way, the "fruit" isn't really tied to the storage.

Comment: Good advice, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @jmucchiello: Yes and No - It is the answer, in that I wouldn't do either.  It's not truly a constant, it's masked behavior over an Xml node "query" for a value.  Neither option is one I'd favor in my code, so I put in what I'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the constants.  It is a *little* more work, but there is no performance impact.  And even if you usually copy/paste the values, I've certainly had instances where I changed code when I typed and didn't realize that Visual Studio had focus.  I'd *much* prefer these resulted in compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, where the Strings are used as keys to a map or dictionary, I would lean toward use of an `enum` (or other object) instead.  You can often do much more with an enum than with a constant string.  In addition, if some code is commented out, IDE's will often miss that when doing a refactor.  Also, references to a String constant that are in comments may or may not be included in a refactor.

I will make a constant for a string when the string will be used in many locations, the string is long or complicated (such as a regex), or when a properly-named constant will make the code more obvious.

I prefer my typos, incomplete refactorings, and other bugs of this sort to fail to compile rather than to just fail to operate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Like many other refactorings, it's an arguably optional additional step that leaves you with code that's less risky to maintain and is more easily grokked by the "next guy".  If you're in a situation that rewards that kind of thing (most that I'm in do), go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pretty much.

I think developers in statically typed languages have an unhealthy fear of anything at all dynamic. Pretty much every line of code in a dynamically typed language is effectively a string literal, and they've been fine for years. For instance, in JavaScript technically this:

```
var x = myObject.prop1.prop2;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var x = window["myObject"]["prop1"]["prop2"]; // assuming global scope
```

But it is definitely *not* a standard practice in JavaScript to do this:

```
var OBJ_NAME = "myObject";
var PROP1_NAME = "prop1";
var PROP2_NAME = "prop2";

var x = window[OBJ_NAME][PROP1_NAME][PROP2_NAME];
```

That would just be ridiculous.

It still depends though, like if a string is used in numerous places and it's rather cumbersome/ugly to type ("name" vs. "my-custom-property-name-x"), then it's probably worth making a constant, even within a single class (at which point it's probably good to be internally consistent within the class and make all the other strings constants too).

Also, if you actually intend for other external users to interact with your library using these constants, then it's also a good idea to define publicly accessible constants and document that users should use those to interact with your library. However, a library which interacts via magic string constants is usually a bad practice and you should consider designing your library in such a way that you don't need to use magic constants to interact with it in the first place.

I think in the specific example you gave, where the strings are relatively simple to type and there are presumably no external users of your API who would expect to work with it using those string values (i.e. they're just for internal data manipulation), readable code is far more valuable than refactorable code, so I would just put the literals directly inline. Again, this is assuming I understand your exact use case specifically.

One thing nobody seemed to notice is that as soon as you define a constant, its scope becomes something to maintain and think about. This actually *does* have a cost, it's not free like everyone seems to think. Consider this:

Should it be private or public in my class? What if some other namespace/package has a need for the same value, should I now extract the constant to some global static class of constants? What if I now need it in other assemblies/modules, do I extract it further? All these things make the code less and less readable, harder to maintain, less pleasant to work with, and more complicated. All in the name of refactorability?

Usually, these "great refactorings" never occur, and when they do they require a complete rewrite anyway, with all new strings. And if you had been using some shared module before this great refactoring (as in the above paragraph) which didn't have these new strings which you now need, what then? Do you add them to the same shared module of constants (what if you don't have access to the code for this shared module)? Or do you keep them local to you, in which case there are now multiple scattered repositories of string constants, all at different levels, running the risk of duplicated constants all over the code? Once you get to this point (and believe me I've seen it), refactoring becomes moot, because while you'll get all *your* usages of *your* constants, you'll miss *other* people's usages of *their* constants, even though these constants have the same logical value as your constants and you're actually trying to change all of them.